# ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina

Tags: installation, tomcat7

I am getting ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina while starting tomcat in catalina.out.

In the console I have got the message "Tomcat is running with pid:XXXX" but when i execute "ps -ef | grep tomcat" , it is not showing tomcat process.

```
  17-May-2017 10:25:32.462 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory.validateFile Problem with directory [/home/dir/"/opt/project_dir/testProject/tomcat/lib"], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
17-May-2017 10:25:32.464 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory.validateFile Problem with directory [/home/dir/"/opt/project_dir/testProject/tomcat/lib/*.jar"], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
17-May-2017 10:25:32.464 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory.validateFile Problem with directory [/home/dir/"/usr/share/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.69/lib"], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
17-May-2017 10:25:32.464 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory.validateFile Problem with directory [/home/dir/"/usr/share/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.69/lib/*.jar"], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:398)
```

Comment: Reinstalling the tomcat worked for me